# How to the compilation speed of the node.js server while running on Vs code?

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, localhost

While running node.js server in vs code, it is taking more time to load how I can solve this issue.[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RQ2v.png)

Comment: VS Theme name ?

Comment: Dose it load earlier fine? And How much time does it take? I can see you are running using 'nodemon', have you tried running using node only? Does it exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: @DhavalDarji Cobalt 2 I guess

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole I also think of that.

Comment: The theme is cobalt2. Earlier it was taking less time. Now I solve that problem by deleting temp files as well as log files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the time taken by your machine to spin the server then i guess you cannot do much about it. If you are using HDD in your machine consider upgrading it to SSD. And if you are speaking about the response sent by the server then [this](https://medium.com/skyshidigital/6-tricks-to-speed-up-and-improve-your-node-js-performance-fadc06d15cbe) link will help you to optimize your node app.
If you are on Windows perform these steps
Open run prompt and type
%temp%
temp
prefetch
Run them individually and delete all the files
2. Clean yout recycle bin
3. Use disk clean utility built-in windows to reduce junk files even more.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will follow it.

Comment: Try deleting useless node modules from your system because they take up lot of space. Accept the answer if it helped you